# Why are $\mathbf{w}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\mathcal{F}$ denote either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ and let $V$ denote an inner product space over $\mathcal{F}$. Let $T$ denote a normal operator on $V$. Let $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ denote elements of $V$ such that
$$||\mathbf{v}|| = 3$$
$$||\mathbf{w}|| = 3$$
$$T\mathbf{v} = 4\mathbf{v}$$
$$T\mathbf{w} = 2\mathbf{w}$$
Find an explicit value for $||T(\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{w})||^2$

I'm able to get up to this point:

$$= 16||\mathbf{v}||^2 - 16 <\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}> + 4 ||\mathbf{w}||^2$$

I don't know how to evaluate $<\mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}>$. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you remind me what normal means in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.  $v$ and $w$ are eigenvectors of a normal operator $T$ with distinct eigenvalues. Therefore they are orthogonal.